# How to print out a check-mark icon on submitted form using PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement, icons, submit, form-submit

This code below will print out a `<i class="far fa-star"></i>` if the `rowCount == 0` and if `> 0` will print out `<i class="fas fa-check"></i>`, after the user submits the form they will not be able to see the `<i class="fas fa-check"></i>` unless they refresh the page, after the user submits the form the page refresh itself, and the user needs to refresh one more time to see the `<i class="fas fa-check"></i>`:

```
if ($rowCountFav == 0) {
  $favIcon = '<i class="far fa-star"></i>';
}else{$favIcon = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  if(isset($_POST["fav"])){ 
    if ($rowCountFav == 0) {
      $favorito = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `favorito` (user_id, nameItem) VALUES (:user_id, :nameItem)");
      $favorito->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $favorito->bindParam(':nameItem', $nameItem, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $favorito->execute();
    }
  } 
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <button class="btnSub btnA" type="submit" name="fav" />
    Favorito <?= $favIcon;?>
  </button> <span class="ml-1 mr-2">-</span> 
</form>
```

**What i want**: i want to print out the `<i class="fas fa-check"></i>` after the user submits the form.

So i tryed this, but nothing changed:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  if(isset($_POST["fav"])){ 
    if ($rowCountFav == 0) {
      $favorito = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `favorito` (user_id, nameItem) VALUES (:user_id, :nameItem)");
      $favorito->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $favorito->bindParam(':nameItem', $nameItem, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $favorito->execute();
    }else{$favIcon = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';} ## I just added this line ##
  } 
}
```

Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check `$rowCountFav` before updating it. The solution is simple, switch the check and query. You'll also need to update the variable value after the query:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  if(isset($_POST["fav"])){ 
    if ($rowCountFav == 0) {
      $favorito = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `favorito` (user_id, nameItem) VALUES (:user_id, :nameItem)");
      $favorito->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $favorito->bindParam(':nameItem', $nameItem, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $favorito->execute();
      $rowCountFav = 1;
    }
  } 
}

if ($rowCountFav == 0) {
  $favIcon = '<i class="far fa-star"></i>';
} else {
  $favIcon = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
}

?>
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <button class="btnSub btnA" type="submit" name="fav" />
    Favorito <?= $favIcon;?>
  </button> <span class="ml-1 mr-2">-</span> 
</form>
```